# Dynamics of a 3R planar robot manipulator,matrices M(q),C(q,q') and G(q)

Tags: dynamics, manipulator

The dynamics equation is T=M(q)*q''+C(q,q')*q'+G(q).

Can somebody provide me with the M(q), C(q,q') and G(q) matrices of a 3R manipulator with link mass,length and rotational inertia m_i, l_i and Inertia_i respectively?

[image: 3Rserial]

Comment: You will find all the necessary information in book of J. J. Craig "Introduction to Robotics: Mechanics and Control (Third Edition)". This book explains that problems in clear and concise way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest approach for deriving the dynamics equation of the manipulator is via Lagrangian approach. I've hand-written in a hurry the equations that you need to start computing the Lagrangian equation in the following picture and I leave the rest for you:

[image]